# JavaScript find out what was selected from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the selected text from what the user selects from my dropdown, here is the html

```
<select id="playerType" onchange="copy();">
<option value="0">Select one</option>
<option value="1">Goalkeepers</option>
<option value="2">Defenders</option>
<option value="3">Midfielders</option>
<option value="4">Forwards</option>
```

and the JavaScript

```
function copy(){
var sel = document.getElementById("playerType");
var selection = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
if(selection == "goalkeeper"){
    textDoc = "goalkeepers.txt";
}
if(selection == "defender"){
    textDoc = "defenders.txt";
}
if(selection == "midfielder"){
    textDoc = "midfielders.txt";
}
if(selection == "forward"){
    textDoc = "forwards.txt";       
}
getAjaxData(textDoc);
```

}

Your help is greatly appreciated..

gman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var selection = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
var selection = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
```

instead of:

```
var selection = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to target the select's innerHTML.  Like so:

```
var somevar = document.getElementById('playerType');
alert(somevar.innerHTML);
```

If you want to get the value any time it is changed then you can do something like:

```
somevar.onchange = function() {
    textDoc = somevar.innerHTML + '.txt';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that handy tip alert(somevar.value); that will help me debug next time.